# Missing dependencies hasSize() and hasProperty() when implementing unit test of Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, dependencies

I am trying to implement a unit test of a method in a Spring MVC controller as follows:

```
@Test
public void testGetProfile() {
    Person mockPerson = new Person();
    mockPerson.setPersonId(1);
    mockPerson.setName("Mr Brown");
    mockPerson.setAddress("Somewhere");
    mockPerson.setTelephone("1234567890"); 
    mockPerson.setEmail("brown@brown.com");

    when(mockPersonService.get(1)).thenReturn(mockPerson);
    try {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/person/profile?personId=1"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("view/profile"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/jsp/view/profile.jsp"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("person", hasSize(1L)))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("person", hasItem(
                    allOf(
                            hasProperty("personId", is(1L)),
                            hasProperty("name", is("Mr Brown")),
                            hasProperty("address", is("Somewhere")),
                            hasProperty("telephone", is("1234567890")),
                            hasProperty("email", is("brown@brown.com")),
                    )
            )));

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Misc.printStackTrace(e);
    }
    verify(mockPersonService, times(1)).get(1);
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockPersonService);        
}
```

But I get messages about dependencies concerning `hasSize(long)` and `hasProperty(...)`.

I have recent versions of Mockito, HamCrest et al in the application's class path.

So what am I missing?

My current imports are:

```
import library.model.Person;
import library.service.PersonService;
import library.util.Misc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext; 
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.hasItem;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
```

Comment: What are the full error messages you are getting? Have you imported `hasSize` and `hasProperty` using static imports?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans and get flyover messages saying 'cannot find symbol method hasProperty(String, Matcher<String>). The messages are not in a stacktrace or compiler listing.

Comment: That sounds like you might not have imported the method. Could you include the imports from your test class in your question?

Comment: I've added them to the question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your imports only include the matchers from hamcrest-core, which are in [`CoreMatchers`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html):

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
```

The `hasProperty` and `hasSize` methods are only in the [`Matchers`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html) class of hamcrest-library, which includes a larger set of matchers. Try to change your import to the following:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

If this does not work, you might only be depending on hamcrest-core. In this case, change your dependency to the hamcrest-library or hamcrest-all artifact. An example for adding this dependency for Maven is below. See the [Hamcrest GitHub page](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest) for some more details.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My thanks to you sir. That has resolved the problem.

Comment: Spring boot with spring-boot-starter-test dependency includes them by default 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html